# AngularJs 1.5.x perform slowly on IE but better on Chrome and safari?

Tags: angularjs, performance

ANy idea what may be reason for IE everything works slow but better on chrome and safari..?

Comment: Please add more context we can't really help you by guessing.. Though my guess is *You might have `ng-repeat` which is rendering **2k+** data, correct?*

Comment: Nopes.. I do have many Isolated state, ng-repeat has hardly 100 data. ANd all component and page is using custom directive

Answer (score -2):

You should use grunt and gulp for improve performance of your angular application.

Comment: Can you explain why so ?

Comment: because it minify js and html . Also you can use lazy load to load js file dynamically.